# Docker does not bind with encrypted hard disk on Windows

Tags: windows, hard-drive, docker, disk-encryption, docker-for-windows

I am using [Datalab](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/) on my Windows Pro PC. Datalab is used through a Docker container. I want to bind the container with my D: hard drive. To do this, I use the following command:

```
docker run -it -p "8081:8080" -v "d/path/:/content" -e "PROJECT_ID=my_project_id" gcr.io/cloud-datalab/datalab
```

This has always worked successfully: I can use Datalab locally using my web browser, and I can access the files on my hard drive at D:\path\datalab

However, after encrypting my hard drive using Bitlocker, it no longer works. I can still use Datalab, but nothing appears on my D: drive at the specified path. However, all files saved using Datalab are persisted the next time I run the command. Yet, I am unable to find these files on my hard drive.

Note that on C: everything works perfectly. Both drives are encrypted using Bitlocker and C: contains my OS files.